# How to assign traffic priority with Sophos UTM 9?

Tags: firewall, sophos, astaro

I'm trying to assign traffic prioritization with a Linux machine (Debian) running Sophos UTM 9.  I can see (and have read) that I can guarantee a service (in this case a specific TCP port) an amount of bandwidth, but this would keep any reserved uplink bandwidth sitting idly by doing nothing, and making everything else run that much slower even when the uplink is not being utilized.

I had thought I could do it by creating a single Bandwidth Pool rule and then adding the different services as traffic selectors but there does not appear to be any way to assign priorities to the traffic selectors within a bandwidth pool.

I'm just looking to have something that will always put the traffic of service x above the traffic of service y, or z.  If the link is full, queue traffic for service x before looking any further.

How does one do that?

Answer (score -1):

The information that your require is available in the article

http://fastvue.co/sophos/blog/limit-youtube-traffic-sophos-utm-qos/

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, please [provide context around links](http://serverfault.com/help/how-to-answer) so others will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. If possible summarise or quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.

Comment: This article talks about download throttling and rate limiting,  not upload prioritization.